# addToBackStack Function is not Working Correctly in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a newbie in android and using android studio 2.2
In my app I've used different fragments and they appear when user click on an ImageView and I've used addToBackStack function for the device back button. It takes me to the exactly previous fragment but it does not highlight the previous Imageview according to the statements when clicked on back button.
Here is the code for fragments

```
public void dates(View view)
{
    if(frag != null)
    {
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon_black));
        date.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Available Dates");
        frag = new AvailableDates();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
public void subscription(View view)
{
    if (frag != null)
    {
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon_black));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon));
        subs.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Subscriptions");
        frag = new Subscription();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The codes you do highlight the previous in which method(oncreate, oncreateview, ....). Could you post the codes?

Comment: I'm highlighting the ImageView in the dates function shared above using this


date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon_black));

Comment: You call `dates` method in which method(onCreate, onCreateView, ....) ?

Comment: I'm calling it direct from the ImageView in the activity. Here it is the ImageView in which I'm calling this.

<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/date_icon"
                android:onClick="dates"
                android:id="@+id/date1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home1"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hightlight/changes when press back, you need to control manually back press like this in your activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            // Now, your AvailableDates fragment resumes, you can hightlight your views again
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and how i'll check in this function that it takes me to which function(fragment) on pressing the back button.